# Offline Address Book Generation issues Exchange 2010 Events 9331 & 9358

Tags: exchange-2010, exchange-2003, public-folders

I am doing a double hop migration from 2003 to 2013. I have already migrated to Exchange 2010 however I think there was a hiccup with the public folders and replication.
All of the public folders are working for clients and can be accessed by everyone but I am getting some errors in the event logs on the exchange server.

I am worried that these are going to cause problems when I do the migration from 2010 to 2013. To confirm again users are not seeing errors only the server. Exchange 2003 has been decommissioned and shut down, the new 2010 server is a single server with all the roles on it.

The two that are bugging me at the moment are Events 9331 and 9358 (source MSExchangeSA), they relate to the generation of the OAB and appear whenever I try to update the OAB or when its update schedule runs.

```
Event ID: 9331    
OABGen encountered error 8004010f (internal ID 501080f) accessing the public folder database while generating the offline address list for address list '\Global Address List'. - \Default Offline Address List

Event ID: 9358
OALGen could not update the timestamp of the previous version of offline address list '\Global Address List'.  Please check earlier event log messages for the specific error. - \Default Offline Address List
```

I have tried a lot already but they still appear, either there's still something wrong or I am not understanding  something.

I've have tried http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Server_Software/Email_Servers/Exchange/Q_26320925.html in which the responses suggest

- adding the reg key "OAL post full if diff fails" w/ a value of 1
- the Default Offline Address Book is selected in the client settings
  of the exchange database
- ensured services are running
- restarted the Microsoft exchange address book service and Microsoft
  exchange file distribution service.
- checked C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ExchangeOAB and C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V14\ClientAccess\OAB for folders with GUID caules and filled with .LZX files

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4a302f7-fc67-4c31-a429-0a19f1eafaa9/oab-issues suggests an issue with permissions and too add iss_usrs to the web.config file but i don,t have a iss_usrs group however authenticated users, system and administrators all have access.

I had a few other minor issues as well which are listed on my spiceworks post (which i cant list as I am a new member and cant put more than two links up), these related to the exchange 2003 server still being referenced for replication and still present in ADSI edit, I followed a post about removing the old exchange server from *CN=Configuration,DC=DOMAIN,DC=LOCAL > CN=Services > CN=Microsoft Exchange > CN=EXCHANGE_ORG > CN=Administrative Groups* using ADSI edit

I apologise for such a long post but I wanted to make sure all the info was up on here

**Update 28/03/2014**

Ok I've been exploring around and found an issue, but not sure if its related. When running Get-MailPublicFolder command some of the returned results are showing a warning.

```
WARNING: The object company.com/Microsoft Exchange System Objects/Conference Calendar has been corrupted, and it's in
an inconsistent state. The following validation errors happened:
WARNING: Property expression "Conference Calendar" isn't valid. Valid values are: Strings formed with characters from A
 to Z (uppercase or lowercase), digits from 0 to 9, !, #, $, %, &, ', *, +, -, /, =, ?, ^, _, `, {, |, } or ~. One or
more periods may be embedded in an alias, but each period should be preceded and followed by at least one of the other
characters. Unicode characters from U+00A1 to U+00FF are also valid in an alias, but they will be mapped to a best-fit
US-ASCII string in the e-mail address, which is generated from such an alias.
```

From what I can tell this is due to exchange 2010 not liking spaces in the name where as exchange 2003 never cared. I am working through changes this now to see if it makes any difference

Comment: What a coincidence, I just discovered we are having a similar issue in our organization that is in the process of finalizing an exchange 2003->2010 migration. Our event ID 9331 is coupled with event ID 9335 however. I'm not the exchange admin, but I'll try to report back with anything I learn that may be helpful.

Comment: managed to sort out the warnings but that hasn't helped still the same issues :(